# Easy and fast way to format a timestamp

Tags: java, performance, datetime, formatting, timestamp

We have some timestamps represented as long in millis since epoch. Within strings for logging, exceptions, or `toString()` methods, these timestamps need to be formatted. A simple and clean format is enough.

So, what is the simplest and fastest method for formatting a timestamp in Java?

Requirements:

- input timestamps represented as long in millis since epoch
- output should be a string
- fast
- low CG overhead
- a simple and clean output is sufficient, since it is only for internal purposes (debugging and logging), e.g. something minimal: 20141220 174522.23
- if possible within JDK
- the time zone is the system time zone

In particular, did somebody did a benchmark of JDK methods that can be used for this?

Actually I don't want to use SimpleDateFormat, since I believe its flexibility comes with too much overhead.

Comment: Have you googled? Did you ready anything about any classes that you  could use here? Did you tried using those classes and what was your observations?

Comment: Just clarified that SimpleDateFormat is not what I am looking for. That is the standard "BigMac" solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Easy to use** and reasonable fast:

```
// All Java versions:
new java.sql.Timestamp(millis).toString(); // 2016-10-29 12:28:41.979

// Recommended when using Java 8+ (about +50% faster than Timestamp), standards compliant format
// checked with jmh 1.15
java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis).toString(); // 2016-10-29T10:28:41.979Z
```

Comment: How do you get `millis`?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons Lang's `FastDateFormat` class is absolutely a good alternative to `SimpleDateFormat`. It's fast and also Thread-Safe ( especially usefull in multi-threaded server environments). All patterns are compatible with `SimpleDateFormat` (except time zones and some year patterns).

The summary of the constructor is :

`FastDateFormat(String pattern, TimeZone timeZone, Locale locale)`

You could find more info at  [FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest implementation is very likely to be:

```
Long.toString(millis);
```

If performance is the most important thing, you should use that.

> Actually I don't want to use SimpleDateFormat, since I believe its flexibility comes with too much overhead.

According to a quick [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark, on my laptop, `Long.toString` gets twelve million ops/second and `SimpleDateFormat` is two million.

What's your budget? Once you know that you'll be able to decide which of those is most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);
```

Or:

```
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
```

Not sure which one is faster though.

To format the Date into a string, you can use SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS"); // should output something like you desired: 20141220 174522.23
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```